# PHP Configuration File Not Loaded? (Mac OS X Yosemite)

Tags: php, macos, apache

First time to post here and I'm a PHP newbie (please go easy on me). I already have **Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)** installed on my Mac running on **OS X 10.10 Yosemite**. I can also successfully run websites on my local machine. However, when I output `phpinfo();` in a browser, it tells me that my configuration file is not loaded:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path | /etc
>
> Loaded Configuration File | (none)

Note that I already have `php.ini` in `/etc`.

Using terminal, I ran the following command: `$ php -i | grep 'Configuration File'` and I got this:

> `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
>   Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini`

Why are `phpinfo();` and  `php -i` showing two different things? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the `php` command in the terminal, you will be getting the CLI version of PHP. You can confirm this by looking for the `Server API` value in the output of `php -i`:

```
$ php -i | grep "Server API"
Server API => Command Line Interface
```

Whereas your Apache server is likely using the `Apache 2.0 Handler` PHP SAPI, which will probably have a different configuration.

Where the default location for php.ini files is is platform-dependent. Still the phpinfo output in the Apache version of PHP might reveal the search paths (i.e. where to put your .ini file). The values to look for in the output of phpinfo should be `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` and `Scan this dir for additional .ini files`.